# How to create an empty folder on Google Storage with Google API?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage

How to create an empty folder on Google Storage with Google API? (Assume that `/` is path separator.)

Comment: checkout google tutorial regarding to uploading images to google storage. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-nodejs/#7

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage does not have folders or subdirectories. However, there is some support for emulating them. gsutil's [How Subdirectories Work](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) is a good read for some background.

Google Cloud Storage objects are a flat namespace, but many tools, including gsutil and the Google Cloud Storage UI, create an illusion of a hierarchical file tree.

There are two widely used conventions for creating the illusion of an empty subdirectory:

1. *(recommended)* Create an object that ends in a trailing slash. For example, to create a subdirectory called `foo` at the root of a bucket, you would create an empty object (size 0) called `foo/`.
2. *(legacy)* Create an object with `_$folder$` appended to the name. For example, to create a subdirectory called `foo` at the root of a bucket, you would create an empty object (size 0) called `foo_$folder$`.

Note that most tools and utilities are using method 1 now. Method 2 is less frequently used.

Comment: This answer is over a year old, so it's possible that things have changed.  If not, can someone tell me exactly how (preferably using gsutil) I can create an empty object with a name ending with '/' ?  I'm hoping to create explicit folders for use with gcsfuse.  Thanks.

Comment: if I create an empty file locally, and try to upload it like this: "gsutil cp dummy_file gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>/" it just creates an empty object at gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>/dummy_file ... and if I try to copy it to an object called gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>_$folder$ I get an object called gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>_$  @jterrace

Comment: The info is current: there's still no way to create a directory placeholder object with gsutil.

Comment: ok, good to know -- can you provide an example of how to do it using an API/endpoint?  (either raw https or python, if possible)

Comment: Currently GCS allows create folders (including nested) in buckets.

Answer (score 53):

@SheRey - looking at folders created via the GCS web interface, the Content-Type is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` but it doesn't really matter. Here's what worked for me in python:

```
# pip install google-cloud-storage

from google.cloud import storage

gcs_client = storage.Client(project='some_project')
bucket = gcs_client.get_bucket('some_bucket')
blob = bucket.blob('some/folder/name/')

blob.upload_from_string('', content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8')
```

Comment: Thanks and congratulations, you've accomplished what Google deemed to be "Infeasible" (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148487275).

Comment: Don't you need to create all the intermediate directories this way?  First `some`, than `some/folder`, than `some/folder/name`?

Comment: @AntonDaneyko no, that is not neccesary.

Answer (score 12):

Thank you for the Question and the chosen  Best answer.
Here is a code snippet that I wrote:
Python Method:

```
def create_folder(bucket_name, destination_folder_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_folder_name)

    blob.upload_from_string('')

    print('Created {} .'.format(
        destination_folder_name))
```

main code that calls the method:

```
folder = create_folder(bucket_name, 'test-folder/')
```

Comment: A lot has changed over the years and this is now the best answer.

Answer (score 11):

**`Node.js` + `@google-cloud/storage@^2.5.0`:**

Only you need do is to assign a destination like: `<folder>/<file Name>` pattern.

For below example, I am using `uuid` as my folder name to simulate each user has a folder to store their own files.

```js
 it('should upload file and create a folder correctly', async () => {
    const myStorage = new Storage({ keyFilename: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../.gcp/cloud-storage-admin.json') });
    const bucket = myStorage.bucket('ez2on');
    const fileName = 'mmczblsq.doc';
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, `../../../tmp/${fileName}`);
    const uuid = faker.random.uuid();

    await bucket.upload(filePath, {
      destination: `${uuid}/${fileName}`,
      gzip: true,
      metadata: {
        cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000'
      }
    });
  });
```

The result is:

[image]

Here is the API docs for `@google-cloud/storage`: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload

**`Go` + `cloud.google.com/go/storage`**

```golang
package main

import (
    "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    opts := option.ClientOption(
        option.WithCredentialsFile(os.Getenv("CredentialsFile")),
    )

    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx, opts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%v", err)
    }
    filename := "mmczblsq.doc"
    filepath := fmt.Sprintf("./tmp/%s", filename)
    file, err := os.Open(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%v", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    uuidIns, err := uuid.NewUUID()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%v", err)
    }
    object := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", uuidIns, filename)
    log.Printf("object name: %s", object)
    wc := client.Bucket("ez2on").Object(object).NewWriter(ctx)
    if _, err := io.Copy(wc, file); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%v", err)
    }
    if err := wc.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%v", err)
    }
}
```

Output of stdout:

```sh
☁  upload [master] ⚡  CredentialsFile=/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/nodejs-gcp/.gcp/cloud-storage-admin.json go run main.go
2019/07/08 14:47:59 object name: 532a2250-a14c-11e9-921d-8a002870ac01/mmczblsq.doc
```

Check the file in google cloud platform console:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

if you are using `java` SDK try this.

```java
Blob folderCreated = bucket.create(folder_name + "/", "".getBytes());
```

1. `folder_name` should end with "/"
2. upload empty bytes

Answer (score 1):

I got through by "creating" the folder when naming the object to be written.

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

blob = bucket.blob("new_folder_name/destination_blob_name")

blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to create a unique subdirectory on Google Storage bucket from CircleCI instance. Here's how i did it using gsutil. I created a dummy file. I also appended my folder name to a destination bucket name with slash.

```
Usage: gsutil cp OBJECT_LOCATION gs://DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME/

sudo gsutil cp ~/some-path/dummyFile.txt gs://my-bucket/unique-folder-name/
```

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me for node

```
import os = require('os');

const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'temp.txt');
fs.writeFileSync(tempFilePath, '');
await admin.storage().bucket().upload(tempFilePath, {
  destination: `other-folders/new-folder/`,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using node.js sdk

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();

async function addEmptyFolder() {
  return storage.bucket('my-bucket')
    .file('folderA/folderB/')
    .save('');
}
```