# GCS storage create folder API

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Having trouble creating folder in a bucket in Google Cloud storage thru a API

I have already tried the `curl` call for the API with all varying possibilities for the request json format.

ABC is not really the organization but gave it to obfuscate real data. I have also setup the variable `$access_token` using gcloud call to get access-token.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" -d '{"displayName":"[vicks]"}' https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v2/folders?parent=ABC
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "field [Folder.display_name] has issue [invalid format]",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "Folder.display_name",
            "description": "invalid format"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am expecting the API call to create the directory but it fails showing error in display_name format though I have followed the document at https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders

Comment: try removing the brackets around "vicks", in the example [DISPLAY_NAME] is used as a placeholder *with* the brackets, so i'm assuming you need to remove them

Comment: Google Cloud Storage actually doesn't have folders, just file paths that look like they contain folders.  The documentation you're linking to is for something else called Resource Manager.

Comment: Hi Doug -  not sure if you visited the URL I had posted. There is a section in the page that URL brings up. Here is a snippet from the page which claims the API can indeed create Folders (I am not debating whether it is folder or not, but the fact that the API is meant to create folder or something in those terms) -  "Creating folders
To create folders, you must have the Folder Admin or Folder Creator role at the parent level. For example, to create folders at the Organization level, you must have one of these roles at the Organization level."  Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the link you provided is about the API that will help you create a folder within your organization and not inside a Cloud Storage bucket. This can be seen by looking at the [first graph](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/img/cloud-folders-hierarchy.png) in the page you linked.

Thankfully, there is still a solution that might help you achieve what you’re looking for. While Google Cloud Storage objects are stored in a flat namespace, tools like gsutil or the even the Google Cloud Console can provide a hierarchical view of the objects by following simple naming rules (it is essentially an emulation of subdirectories).

1) To treat an object as a directory, you can create an empty object that ends with “/”. If you want a subdirectory called ‘abc’ then you can call the object ‘abc/’ and gsutil will treat it like an empty directory. To insert an object/file into the subdirectory, you may simply copy an object/file to the destination URL including ‘abc’ such as “gs://your-bucket/abc”.

2) Another less commonly used way is to create an empty object that ends with “*$folder$”. If you want a subdirectory called ‘abc’ then you can call the object ‘abc*$folder$’ and gsutil will treat it like an empty directory. Similarly to the previous point, to insert an object/file into the subdirectory, you may simply copy an object/file to the destination URL including ‘abc’ such as “gs://your-bucket/abc”.

I would highly suggest you read through [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) to get a great understanding of how Google Cloud Storage subdirectories work. Additionally, I’ve found [another previously answered stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416598/how-to-create-an-empty-folder-on-google-storage-with-google-api) that is very relevant to your question and can be of great help to you as well.

Comment: Hi @jado06  Thank you very much for the detailed answer explaining this is not really dir in cloud storage rather somewhere else. We came to the same conclusion based on trial and error (A big shout out to my developer). We really appreciate everyone who commented on this thread.