# Dynamic bucket creation gcp

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Can anybody help if we can create bucket folder in google cloud storage based on year month and date programmatically? I don't want to create manually as it will be difficult to create a bucket folder each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buckets don't have folders or subdirectories. Please have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork). However, you can use the workaround described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416598/how-to-create-an-empty-folder-on-google-storage-with-google-api) and create a folder through the API. I would put the code in a Cloud Function.

Please note that you should give the required permissions to the App Engine service account as Cloud Functions is using that account and then you can trigger this function with Cloud Scheduler and Pub/Sub by following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub).